# Trigonometry behind Ego Motion (Visual Odometry)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, mathematical-modeling, computer-vision

I've cropped this below picture from the journal: [A Robust Visual Odometry and Precipice Detection System Using Consumer-grade Monocular Vision](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~personalrover/PER/ResearchersPapers/CampbellSukthankarNourbakhshPahwa_VisualOdometryCR.pdf)

[image]

Here it says,

- $(u,v)$ denotes for pixel coordinate and $(x,y)$ denote the coordinate of 2D ground plane. $u$ increment from left to right and $v$ increment from top to bottom of the frame.
- $U$, $V$ are the width and the height of image in pixels respectively.
- VFOV & UFOV are field of view angles in vertical direction and, horizontal direction respectively.
- $H$ is the height of the camera center from the ground and $D$ is the distance between the robot to the intersection of the principal ray.

What I didn't understand is, that the above journal states these following trigonometric relation:

> $$\tan\beta = (2v-V)\tan(\text{VFOV}/2)$$
>
> $$ z = {H \cos\beta\over\sin(\alpha + \beta)}$$

I would much appreciate if someone can help me out on this. Please check the page 3 of the paper if need more clarification on this.

Thanking You!

Comment: The first relation should be, I think, $\tan\beta={2v-V\over V}\tan(\text{VFOV/2})$.

Comment: Can you prove it please...

Comment: That formula is not dimensionally consistent: it has a dimensionless quantity on the left and a length on the right. As no unit length was defined, there must be something wrong. My version can be proved if $V$ is the length of the gray line near to $v$.